# Spring Data JPA Null pointer Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPOoU.jpg)I am new to Spring Boot Data JPA repository. This is my first application with JPA. I am trying to get data from DB. But which returns NULL.

**Entity File**

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "TASK_DETAILS")
public class TaskDetails {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "TASK_DETAILS_ID")
private long taskDetailsId;

@Column(name = "TASK_NAME")
private String TaskName;

@Column(name = "TASK_POLLING_TIME")
private int TaskTime;

@Column(name = "TASK_FILE")
private String TaskClassFile;

@Column(name = "TASK_STATUS")
private String TaskStatus;

public long getTaskDetailsId() {
return taskDetailsId;
}

public void setTaskDetailsId(long taskDetailsId) {
this.taskDetailsId = taskDetailsId;
}

public String getTaskName() {
return TaskName;
}

public void setTaskName(String taskName) {
TaskName = taskName;
}

public int getTaskTime() {
return TaskTime;
}

public void setTaskTime(int taskTime) {
TaskTime = taskTime;
}

public String getTaskClassFile() {
return TaskClassFile;
}

public void setTaskClassFile(String taskClassFile) {
TaskClassFile = taskClassFile;
}

public String getTaskStatus() {
return TaskStatus;
}

public void setTaskStatus(String taskStatus) {
TaskStatus = taskStatus;
}
}
```

**Repository File**

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface TaskDetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<TaskDetails, String> {

TaskDetails findByTaskDetailsId(final long id);
}
```

**My Main Method**

```
@Service
public class ImportAmazonData {

@Autowired
private TaskDetailsRepository taskDetailsRepositoryDAO;

public void getProductsFromAmazonStore(JobExecutionContext context) throws ClassNotFoundException {
final long taskID = (long) context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap().get("taskId");

TaskDetails taskDetails = taskDetailsRepositoryDAO.findByTaskDetailsId(taskID);
System.out.println("Result : " + taskDetails.getTaskClassFile());
}
}
```

**ProductSync File**

```
   import com.example.Schedular.AmazonSync.ImportAmazonData;
    import org.quartz.Job;
    import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
    import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    public class ProductSync implements Job {

    @Autowired
    private ImportAmazonData importAmazonData;

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        try {
            importAmazonData.getProductsFromAmazonStore(context);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here i am trying to get the TaskDetails by id. But my taskDetailsRepositoryDAO was null. Here i have attached my error log. Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

**ERROR LOG**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.example.Schedular.AmazonSync.ImportAmazonData.getProductsFromAmazonStore(ImportAmazonData.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.Schedular.SyncData.ProductSync.execute(ProductSync.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202) ~[quartz-2.3.2.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573) [quartz-2.3.2.jar:na]
```

Comment: Can you share the project structure. ie path of spring boot main class ,entity and repository file.

Comment: Hi, can you show the `ProductSync` class?
Also, package naming must be in lower-case, from Oracle's doc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html


"Package names are written in all lower case to avoid conflict with the names of classes or interfaces."

Comment: @JobyWilsonMathews I have added my project structure

Comment: @EzhilArasu  How are you getting the object of ImportAmazonData class and calling the method that fails ? Please share that code

Comment: @R.G I have added ImportAmazonData for you reference. Can you please check ant let me know

Comment: @EzhilArasu That is the reason for NPE . You need to autowire ImportAmazonData bean

Comment: When you are using `new` keyword , the instance created is not managed by Spring container.

Comment: @R.G Yes it was autowired. Eventhough i am getting Null pointer exception

Comment: Now the reason is `ProductSync` is not a bean . Could you please annotate the class with `@Component` , autowire the instance and trigger the call ?

Comment: @R.G Eventhough it was not working

Comment: @EzhilArasu , what is not working ? Share the stack trace . Share the exact code that fails . If `importAmazonData` is autowired by the container , there will not be any NPE. So what is the error now ?

Comment: @R.G I just changed the class name of ImportAmazonData to ImportAmazonDataService. 

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at com.example.Schedular.SyncData.ProductSync.execute(ProductSync.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
 at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202) ~[quartz-2.3.2.jar:na]
 at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573) [quartz-2.3.2.jar:na]

Comment: @EzhilArasu 1. Annotate the class `ProductSync` with `@Component` so that the class will be auto detected as a bean . 2. If the code still fails , please share the code from the start . i.e from the controller class if one exists or from the main method to start the application

Comment: @R.G Please let me know your MAIL ID to share the project

Comment: Could you please upload the code to the github repository and share the link here? You basically need to share one code flow , either from controller / main method , till the error.

Comment: @R.G  https://github.com/Ezhilarasu1330/AmazonSyncSchedular.git

Comment: @EzhilArasu application runs for me when I modified the db to h2 for testing purposes. Hibernate had dialect incorrect , is that your issue ?  How do you trigger `ProductSync` ? What are the steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @R.G If you are using Mysql just create database. while running the application it will create table.

Comment: @EzhilArasu without db entries , the application wont work as expected. I guess you missed that info in the repository. Other than that the code works connected to MySQL db without any issues

Comment: @R.G i have entires in my database as well

Comment: @EzhilArasu I meant , I do not have those entries to test your project, hence unable to debug any further

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your spring boot main file(I think it is SchedularApplication)
@EnableJpaRepositories("your jpa repository package name")

Answer (score -1):

In your repository file i.e TaskDetailsRepository should be as below :

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface TaskDetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<TaskDetails, Long> {

Optional<TaskDetails> findByTaskDetailsId(Long id);
}
```

Use wrappers instead of primitives in your domain classes.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "TASK_DETAILS_ID")
private Long taskDetailsId;
```

If your are trying to find a record on basis of a particular value then specify that type i.e. **Long**.
And always use Optional if your method is going to return a sing record from database. this will help you resovle NullPointers.

This might help you.

Comment: I have tried the same. Still the my autowired taskDetailsRepositoryDAO was null

Comment: It is not required to put @Repository annotation over the Interface that extends from JpaRepository, what spring does is it creates a proxy class which is available during runtime that is injected afterwards